# Package and deploy spring boot project into war success with profile, but cannot reach the page when I try to visit the page

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

After I successfully get the war file from gradle build, and I deploy to tomcat container, which also success. But when I try to visit `localhost:9999/fdr/test`, it tells me `This site can’t be reached`

Tomcat version I use was apache-tomcat-9.0.22. I already change the build.gradle file to add `providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'` under `dependencies` section. Also in order to let Tomcat know the profile I use, I add `spring.profiles.active=@activeProfiles@` in `application.properties` and also have `application-dev.properties` in `src\main\resource` folder. The way I generate the war file is `./gradlew -PactiveProfiles=dev clean build`, once the war file generated, I put it in `webapps` folder under Tomcat, and start it

For `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.vincent.wartest'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

processResources {
    filter org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
            activeProfiles: activeProfiles
    ]
}



dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation('mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.13')

}
```

The structure looks like following:

```
V:\IDEA\PHOENIX\SRC
├───main
│   ├───java
│   │   └───com
│   │       └───vincent
│   │           └───wartest
│   │               └───phoenix
│   │                   │   lombok.config
│   │                   │   PhoenixApplication.java
│   │                   │   ServletInitializer.java
│   │                   │
│   │                   └───controller
│   │                           PhoenixController.java
│   │
│   └───resources
│       │   application-dev.properties
│       │   application.properties
│       │
│       ├───static
│       └───templates
└───test
    └───java
        └───com
            └───vincent
                └───wartest
                    └───phoenix
                            PhoenixApplicationTests.java
```

Since the code is generated by Intellij automatically, it created a class called `ServletInitializer.java` with following

```java
package com.vincent.wartest.phoenix;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(PhoenixApplication.class);
    }

}
```

In `com.vincent.wartest.controller`, it have simple controller class

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/fdr")
@Slf4j
public class PhoenixController {

    @GetMapping(value="/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test(){
        LOGGER.info("Logger test");
        return new ResponseEntity<>("First test", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Expected Result: after I deploy on tomcat, when I visit `http://localhost:9999/fdr/test`, the page should display `First test`, and response code is 200 OK (by checking F12 on Chrome)

Actual Result: When I visit the page, I got `This site can’t be reached` via Tomcat is running properly

**UPDATE:**
Here is the log on `catalina.out`

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2019-07-16 14:27:46.447  INFO 28080 --- [           main] com.itsp.fdr.phoenix.ServletInitializer  : Starting ServletInitializer on hospt1 with PID 28080 (C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\phoenix-0.0.1\WEB-INF\classes started by zhibo in C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\bin)
2019-07-16 14:27:46.450  INFO 28080 --- [           main] com.itsp.fdr.phoenix.ServletInitializer  : The following profiles are active: dev
2019-07-16 14:27:47.546  INFO 28080 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1037 ms
2019-07-16 14:27:48.074  INFO 28080 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-07-16 14:27:48.437  INFO 28080 --- [           main] com.vincent.wartest.phoenix.ServletInitializer  : Started ServletInitializer in 2.559 seconds (JVM running for 5.498)
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.481 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.508 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\phoenix-0.0.1.war] has finished in [4,388] ms
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.509 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\docs]
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\docs] has finished in [19] ms
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\examples]
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.751 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\examples] has finished in [223] ms
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.751 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\host-manager]
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.780 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [28] ms
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.780 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\manager]
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.797 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\manager] has finished in [16] ms
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.797 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\ROOT]
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.812 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [15] ms
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.815 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.823 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
16-Jul-2019 14:27:48.826 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [4,736] milliseconds
```

It actually load my dev profiles, which I configure `server.port=9999`, so I expected on port 9999 it will start my page.

Comment: Check listening port is actually 9999, also, look in logs to check if app was effectively deployed.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I edit the question to add the catalina log

Answer (score 0):

From your logs:

> Deployment of web application archive [C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\phoenix-0.0.1.war] has finished in [4,388] ms

On tomcat, application root context is named after the war name, in this case: `phoenix-0.0.1`.
So your aplication will be under

http://localhost:9999/phoenix-0.0.1/fdr/test

If you want to keep the version in the context path the war could be better named `phoenix##0.0.1.war`.
So your aplication would be under

http://localhost:9999/phoenix/0.0.1/fdr/test

Comment: Tried using ```http://localhost:9999/phoenix-0.0.1/fdr/test``` and it still not reachable, and none of the files under ```apache-tomcat-9.0.22\logs``` was updated

Comment: try 127.0.0.1:9999, also try renaming your war to phoenix.war, new url should be http://127.0.0.1:9999/phoenix/fdr/test and check what IP is port 9999 bind to, if it's 0.0.0.0:9999 the it's listening on all IPs.

Comment: ```Connecting To 127.0.0.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 9999: Connect failed```, same with localhsot

Comment: so port in not opened, tomcat is not running or is listening on another port. Or, there's a firewall blocking the connection.